# create a split partition in oracle by increasing dinamically the splits

Tags: mysql, plsql, partitioning

Good evening,

I have to insert the values ​​from a table into another using the split partitioning;  *the partition is a range type and the range of values ​​starts from 1 that corresponds to January and ends with 12 that corresponds to December*, the goal is to make a check:

1. if the partition exists, I must insert in the table the values ​​corresponding to that partition
2. if the partition does not exist, I have to create a split of the main partition and then insert into the table the values ​​corresponding to this split of the partition.
3. This increase in split values ​​must be set dynamically, so that I do not have to rewrite split partitioning 12 times

Thanks for the help, if is not clear i'll give more details

Comment: add what you have tried till now. and explain it properly

Comment: Oracle is a brand and brand name of a database, Oracle also has a database called MySQL so which one are you using Oracle database or MySQL?

Comment: i'm using MySQL  untill now i've just   did this way:
begin 
execute immediate 'alter table my_table split partition ||mypartition||' into
(partition '||mypartition1|| values less than ||2|| segment create immediate,
partition '||mypartition2|| values less than ||3|| segment create immediate,

and so on untille mypartition12 but this splits must be increased dinamicall and not manually like this

Comment: Tag properly!!!  MySQL <> Oracle!!!

Comment: @GiuseppeArena - "until now" meaning some other product does it that way?  Well, RDBMS products are mostly incompatible.  So, keep the MySQL manual handy.

Comment: it was my first tag,but my bad i'm using pl/sql not mysql

Answer (score 0):

Splitting is called `REORGANIZE PARTITION`.

To see what partitions you currently have, use `information_schema`.`partitions`.  From that, and the knowledge of the pattern would like, and (preferably) your naming conventions for the partitions, deduce whether to split.

This is better done in a `cron` job or `EVENT` just before a new partition is needed.  That is best if the data comes in roughly chronologically.  If the data comes in with random timestamps, please elaborate.

Meanwhile, [*here*](http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/partitionmaint) is a discussion on how to do a sliding set of partitions for time-based data, plus several tips.

What will you do after December?  I hope you will not overwrite January.  I hope you are using `PARTITION BY RANGE`; otherwise, you cannot get partition pruning for any range test.

Comment: Yes,i'm using range partition,what i will do after december is not important,because the table is complete ,i'
I'm simply making a range partition   of data brought into the new table from the old one

Comment: Are you hoping for a performance improvement?  Or is there some other reason for adding partitioning?

Comment: I'm learning the partitions, I have this exercise asking me to split a range partition, this rangepartition has two values ​​1 and maxvalue which is equivalent to 12. I have to split the max value in 11 partitions from 2 to 12 but I have to do this split dynamically, I can not just split it into 12 parts like I found everywhere

Comment: @GiuseppeArena - If you are talking about `SUBPARTITIONs`, I say "don't bother--they provide no benefit".

Comment: Nope i have to use only split partition, it should work in this way:

Start with a partition by range with values ​​1 and 12. After I check the month (numerical value between 1 and 12) if the partition of the controlled month exists I insert the partitioned values ​​in the table otherwise I create the partition and insert it, to create it I have to make a split on the maximum value of the partition for range that is 12 and I have to divide it from the value 2 to the value 12. I hope it is clearer

Comment: Will January, 2019 items go into the same partition as Jan, 2018?  If so, what is the advantage in the 12 partitions??

Comment: Hi,thx for the comment,but in the end i've done the exercise. Thx again and have a nice day

Comment: @GiuseppeArena - My worry is that you learned mis-information by the exercise.  Is this some class?  Or online tutorial?

Comment: ,dear rick is  a tutorial to be  inserted into the world of work

Comment: That tutorial, as it stands, may be more harmful than beneficial.  (My opinion.)